# How to convert a string to milliseconds?

Tags: javascript, parsing

I have a string like this "00:01:26.830" showing a start time from zero, which is about 1 minute and 26 seconds.

How do I automate this parsing and get amount of milliseconds having the string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a simple [`String.prototype.split()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) to extract each part and then multiply them by their respective conversion factors:

```js
const str = '00:01:26.830';
const [h, m, s, ms] = str.split(/[:.]/).map(Number);
const total = h * 60 * 60 * 1000 + m * 60 * 1000 + s * 1000 + ms;

console.log(total);
```

The same could be done using [`String.prototype.match()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) if you want a bit more control over the format:

```js
const str = '00:01:26.830';
const [match, h, m, s, ms] = (str.match(/^(\d{2}):(\d{2}):(\d{2})\.(\d{3})$/) || []).map(Number);
const total = h * 60 * 60 * 1000 + m * 60 * 1000 + s * 1000 + ms;

console.log(total);

// However, it will not match if the format is slightly different:
const [match2, h2, m2, s2, ms2] = ('00:01:26:830'.match(/^(\d{2}):(\d{2}):(\d{2})\.(\d{3})$/) || []).map(Number);

console.log(match2, h2, m2, s2, ms2);
```

Note both `String.prototype.split()` and `String.prototype.match()` return an array of `string`s, so you need to call [`parseInt()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt) or [`Number()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/Number) with each element.

Answer (score 0):

You can combine [String.prototype.split()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_split.asp) and [parseInt()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_parseint.asp) to achive your goal. Here's your solution, with [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0a16L3fj/1/).

```js
const arr = "00:01:26.830".split(":");

let ms = 0;

ms += parseInt(arr[0]) * 60 * 60 * 1000; // Hours
ms += parseInt(arr[1]) * 60 * 1000; // Minutes

const sec = arr[2].split(".");

ms +=
  parseInt(sec[0]) * 1000 +
  parseInt(sec[1])

console.log(ms);
```

Answer (score 0):

First split the string into its component parts (hours, minutes, seconds)

```js
const timer = "00:01:26.830"
const splitTimerStrings = timer.split(":")
```

Next convert the strings into their actual numbers ("5" should be 5)

```js
const splitTimer = splitTimerStrings.map(n => parseFloat(n))
```

Finally, calculate the milliseconds from the array representing `[hours, minutes, seconds]`

```js
const totalMilli = splitTimer[0] * 3600000 + splitTimer[1] * 60000 + splitTimer [2] * 1000
```

And you should end up with:

> 86830 milliseconds

If you need to do this often, then it can be created into a function like this:

```js
function convertTimeToMilli(stringTimeInput) {
  const splitTimerStrings = timer.split(":")
  const splitTimer = splitTimerStrings.map(n => parseFloat(n))
  const totalMilli = splitTimer[0] * 3600000 + splitTimer[1] * 60000 + splitTimer [2] * 1000

  return totalMilli
}
```

And use it like this:

```js
convertTimeToMilli("00:01:26.830")  // 86830
```